# C++ array member without initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I tried to write an "inline-vector" class for storing a number of elements on the stack conveniently:

```
template<typename T, size_t size_ = 256>
struct InlineVector{
    T content[size_];
    size_t num;

    T() : num(0) {}

    ~T() { for(size_t s = 0; s < num; s++){ content[s]->~T(); } }

    template<typename _Up, typename... _Args>
    void emplace_back(_Args&&... __args) { new (&content[num++]) T(__args); }

    T& get(size_t i) { assert(i < num); return content[i]; }


}
```

For efficiency reasons, I want that `content` is not initialized in `X`'s constructor, even if `T` has only a non-trivial constructor. As you see, the content is intialized later with placement new when it is actually inserted.  However, C++ seems to enforce that all elements of `content` must be initialized in the initialization of `X`. For example, this does not compile:

```
struct Y{ Y(int){} }

X<Y> foo; // compile error, no constructor for Y is called in the construction of X
```

So, how is it possible to have an array member that is not initialized, even if the array element type needs a constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By making the array an array of `char`s and later placement `new`-ing into it. `char` is the only type you're allowed to do this with.

Whilst you're at it, then, you might as well write your own *allocator* instead (with the array as one of its members), and plug it into `std::vector` rather than re-inventing the whole shebang.

```
std::vector<int, YourAllocatorType<int, 256>> v;
```

Comment: Interesting idea with the allocator. And thanks for the actual answer of using a `char` array, as the allocator would have the same problem as the vector. Seems there is no way around the `char` array, no matter whether writing an allocator or a vector.

Comment: @gexicide: Yep not really :)

Answer (score 1):

> So, how is it possible to have an array member that is not initialized, even if the array element type needs a constructor?

It's not for `T x[n]`... but you can point any old `T*` at properly aligned uninitialised memory, then manage your own ad-hoc construction and destruction.  You could also explore creating a `union` with your type and say a `char`, and have an array of the unions....

Comment: I don't think `union` is permitted with members with non-trivial constructors. But it's not needed; a char array and cast is fine and as long as one of the types is `char`, well defined.

Comment: @JanHudec: there are restrictions around the type, but I believe they were relaxed substantially for C++11... certainly something to keep in mind.  Don't have time to dig for exact details myself right now....